# How to call this method when touched on piechart in core plot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

Code for adding piechart

```
pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
pieChart.dataSource = self;
pieChart.pieRadius = 100.0;
pieChart.identifier = @"PieChart1";
pieChart.startAngle = M_PI_4;
pieChart.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionCounterClockwise;
pieChart.delegate = self;


self.pieData =   [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:90.0], 
                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:60.0],
                  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:60.0],nil];

[graph addPlot:pieChart];
```

and i want to call the below method for detecting touch on pie chart

```
-(BOOL)angle:(CGFloat)touchedAngle betweenStartAngle:(CGFloat)startingAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)endingAngle
```

Comment: What method?  It's hard to tell what you're after here.

Comment: specified in the body i m talking about above delegate

Comment: "above delegate"?  Let's pretend I can't see the code on your screen.  Describe the problem you're trying to solve in more detail and you will have more success getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is a private CPTPieChart method. The signature of the public delegate method is:

```
-(void)pieChart:(CPTPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

The pie chart uses your data and the inner and outer radii to determine which slice was touched and calls this delegate method with the index of the slice.